# Passing a variable into URL with AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I'm working on a system management and I'm started from a open source project. The purpose of this SM, is to manage the orders.

My problem is, essentially, display all the data that there are in my DB table (is the list of all orders) and show it in a PHP page. The problem is that are more than 800,000 lines.

The pagination approach is made with DataTable library JS, so the list of page and some elements like that, are managed by datatable.

I should get, ideally, the number of current page added to the SQL request, the value of limit because display 800,000 lines is too slow. I have not the  `<form>` for getting the value of current page, so I should do this with AJAX and then edit my SQL request adding LIMIT. This is my code:

```
<div>
    <div>   
        <table class="table tabe-hover table-bordered" id="list">
            <!-- <colgroup>
                <col width="5%">
                <col width="15%">
                <col width="25%">
                <col width="25%">
                <col width="15%">
            </colgroup> -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center"></th>
                    <th>Corriere</th>
                    <th>Prodotti</th>
                    <th>Consegna</th>
                    <th>Dettagli</th>
                    <th>Dett.Spedizione</th>
                    <th>Totale</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $qry = $conn->query("SELECT en.id_order, en.reference, en.total_paid, en.date_add, s.identificativo_ordine, en.id_cart
                from develettronw.ww_ps_orders en 
                inner join smarty.orders s on en.id_order = s.id_ps
                order by en.date_add desc limit 10000");
                $i = 0;
                while($row= $qry->fetch_assoc()):
                    $i ++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <?php 
                            echo "<b>".$row['date_add'] . "</b><br>";
                            echo "ID PRESTA : <b>" .  $row['id_order'] . "</b><br>";
                            echo "ID : <b>" .  $row['identificativo_ordine'] . "</b><br>";
                            echo "REFERENZA: <b>" .  $row['reference'] . "</b><br>";
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><b>VUOTO</b></td>
                    <td><b>VUOTO</b></td>
                    <td><b>VUOTO</b></td>
                    <td><b>VUOTO</b></td>
                    <td><b>VUOTO</b></td>
                    <td><b><?php echo (number_format($row['total_paid'],2,'.')) ?> €</b></td>
                </tr>   
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    table td{
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#list').dataTable({  
            stateSave: true     

        })
            var table = $('#list').DataTable();
            var info = table.page.info();
            //alert(JSON.stringify(info));
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "index.php",
                data: "currentpage="(info.page+1),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(info.page+1);
                },
            success: function(response) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert("no");
            }
            });
    })
</script>
```

The URL of this page is : index.php?page=articoli

So, how can i get the value of current page, stored in a php variable (?) and add to the SQL REQUEST ?

Edit:

I trying to follow the doc here : https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

So i try to edit my code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#list').DataTable();
    var info = table.page.info();
    table({ 
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
        "url": "index.php?page=ordini",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.myKey = "currentPage";
            d.custom = (info.page+1);
            // etc
        }
    })

})
```

But that's still not working. There is maybe another solution?

Comment: _"This is my code:"_ - of what, the `index.php`? Then `"url": "index.php?page=ordini"` makes little sense; you can not just return HTML code when you use the server-side processing option, you need to return JSON - https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, jquery data tables provide a built in support for server side pagination.
Documentation for the same can be found on this -
[Link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

set these two variables while initializing datatables - processing": true,"serverSide": true,
and set your url in here - "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php".
Datatable set the appropriate variables that your backend code can handle.

Since you are working in PHP, you can directly check the code in the given link.

Comment: I don't understand why when i add this part of code (this one in the doc), my pagination bar  disappear :/

Comment: do some debug processes -  1. check if you have added the proper css files. 2. check for the HTML  and compare with the given HTML 3. check if the api is sending the proper response as mentioned in the ajax. Also I would suggest you to share your code errors after you added this.

Comment: yes i update the question. At the moment whenn i add the part "data", all is not working.

Comment: Have you checked the JSON your code is sending. Try and check the whole code that is mentioned. What you are still trying to do is, rendering the table using your AJAX and then setting the data table on the HTML table rendered by your API. Instead what you are supposed to do is use Datatable itself to render the table. (Observe how tbody is not being mentioned in the code). Your API response needs to be updated. then hook the ajax with the datatable. check the documentation https://datatables.net/manual/server-side (properly). if you are not able to complete this I will create a sample fiddle.

Comment: Sorry but JS for me is very strange XD i'm not able to do this, can u give me a simple exemple so can i understand how it work?